# How to keep routerLinkActive set when routing to another component page related to current page?

Tags: angular

When routing to myloans the navigation link is active but when I click the button on that page to route to syncmyloans the navigation is no longer active. How to keep the navigation active when routing to related sub pages of the main navigation page?

Navigation

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/home']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/myloans']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" class="nav-link">My Loans</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Routing Module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'myloans', component: MyLoansComponent },
  { path: 'syncmyloans', component: SyncLoansComponent },
```

HTML

```
<button type="submit" [routerLink]="['/syncmyloans']" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md btn-rounded shadow custom pt-2 pl-3">
    <span>Sync My Loans</span>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right ml-5" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
</button>
```

Routing module now

```
 { path: 'myloans', component: MyLoansComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'syncmyloans', component: SyncLoansComponent }
    ]  
  }];
```

button

```
<button type="submit" [routerLink]="['/myloans/syncmyloans']" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md btn-rounded shadow custom pt-2 pl-3">
    <span>Sync My Loans</span>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right ml-5" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Use router link options to set the path match to partial, perhaps?

Comment: Not a solutions

Comment: Yeah that's the point and why it's a comment. _Actually related_ routes from the router's perspective share a common prefix or other common element. It can't read your mind and know that two completely dissimilar routes are somehow supposed to be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add routing properly. This is a simple routing concept.
Currently your all routes are at same level.

The correct way of implementing this is, you will need to make `SyncLoansComponent` children route your of `MyLoansComponent` .

This will lead you to implement child routes in Routes array like this :-

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'myloans', component: MyLoansComponent,
    children: [
     { path: 'syncmyloans', component: SyncLoansComponent}
    ]
  }
 ];
```

So, now your path will be like `{{your_app_url}}/myloans/syncmyloans`

Now to render your child component i.e. syncmyloans you will need to use `<router-outlet>` in your parent component at the place where you want to render your child component.

Furthermore, refer to this link to implement child routes in angular.

https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-nested-routing-child-routes-example/

Comment: This does keep the navigation highlighted but the button still doesn't navigate to the new component page. Any thoughts on why?

Answer (score 1):

According to the router, they aren't related.

You can

1. `SyncLoansComponent` a child route of `MyLoansComponent` so the URL will be `"myloans/syncmyloans"`
2. Or, you can manually add the `"active"` class to your nav bar by listening to the router and including your own logic to set some variable.